# Prove $(\neg B \to \neg A) \to (A \to B)$ from axioms

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

How can I prove that 
$$(\neg B \to \neg A) \to (A \to B),$$

if it is told that

1. $A \to (B \to A),$
2. $(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C)),$
3. $(\neg B \to \neg A) \to ((\neg B \to \neg A) \to \neg B).$

Comment: I assume that $!$ means negation. Are you sure about the last axiom?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a proof of [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).  Note that $((\neg B)\implies (\neg A))\iff (A\implies B)$ and this does not need any additional hypotheses, so your first line having "*if it is told that...*" is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Strange, because at lesson we had to prove other using following hypotheses

Comment: I am not so sure about the triviality of this form of contraposition. I think it requires the excluded middle, i.e. it does not hold in (say) intuitionistic logic.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @JMoravitz No, it's not irrelevant. There's no reason why $(\neg q\to \neg p)\to (p\to q)$ should hold without axioms. And it doesn't.

Comment: The second "axiom" is ill-formed.

Comment: In intuitionistic logic, one can get $(\neg b \to \neg a) \leftrightarrow (a\to \neg\neg b)$, and so a priori not $a\to b$, so what hypotheses you use *is* relevant

Comment: The third axiom makes no sense ... should the first $\neg A$ be just $A$ and the last $\neg B$ just $B$? Also, the second axiom should have a few more parentheses

Comment: This question looks like a giant transcription error.

Comment: I've edited the question to change all "$\implies$" to "$\to$", as usually the former means _logical consequence_ (part of semantics) and the latter _material conditional_ (part of syntax). This makes more sense, but please let me know if my interpretation is wrong, so we can rollback to previous edit.

Comment: @Ennar I think that is a good edit. I am used to that very convention, so find it very confusing when $\Rightarrow$ is ised for the material conditional.  I'll change my Answer accordingly later today.

Comment: Why you have not accepted any of the answers below ? If you are not satisfied, please comment on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second axiom needs some more parentheses. I suggest:

$$(A \implies (B \implies C)) 
\implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))$$

More pressingly, your third axiom makes little sense. I am guessing you misstated it. I bet it should be:

$$(\neg B \implies A) \implies ((\neg B \implies \neg A) \implies B)$$

Finally, let's assume you are allowed the use of the Deduction Theorem.

Then we can do:

1. $\neg B \implies \neg A$ Premise
2. $A$ Premise
3. $A \implies (\neg B \implies A)$ Axiom 1
4. $\neg B \implies A$ MP 2,3
5. $(\neg B \implies A) \implies ((\neg B \implies \neg A) \implies B)$ Axiom 3
6. $(\neg B \implies \neg A) \implies B$ MP 4,5
7. $B$ MP 1,6

Thus, we have shown $\neg B \implies \neg A, A \vdash B$

By the Deduction Theorem it thus follows that $\neg B \implies \neg A \vdash A \implies B$

And applying the Deduction Theorem on that, we get $\vdash (\neg B \implies \neg A) \implies (A \implies B)$

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this problem as stated is impossible to solve.

Consider a model where $\lnot$ always returns a truth value of true, and ⟹ is the usual material conditional.  But, then all of the axioms hold true.  But, the conclusion can be false since if B is false and A is true, then ((¬B⟹¬A)⟹(A⟹B)) is false.

Maybe the third axiom got misstated?